# Rendering a bidimensional array with squares in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I want to render a table with squares (like on tabletop games, chess for example). 
Here is my code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
SDL_Rect newSDL_Rect(int xs, int ys, int widths, int heights)
{
    SDL_Rect rectangular;
    rectangular.x = xs;
    rectangular.y = ys;
    rectangular.w = widths;
    rectangular.h = heights;
    return rectangular;
}
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;
    SDL_Rect rects[15][13];
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) //Init the video driver
    {
        printf("SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL 2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN); //Creates the window
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        printf("SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, 0, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED); //renderer used to color rects

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 51, 102, 153, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            {
                rects[i][j] = newSDL_Rect(20 + i*42, 20 + j*42, 40, 40);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 102, 0, 255);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rects[i][j]);
            }

        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_Delay(5000);
    }
}
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

But when i execute my code entirely, the window that is created is blank (all white) for 5 seconds (as the SDL_Delay is running). I don't know how to debug SDL, because i am new to it.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In `newSDL_Rect` you are not returning `rectangular` or it's just a typo ?

Comment: It was a typo, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `newSDL_Rect` function does not return anything.

```
SDL_Rect newSDL_Rect(int xs, int ys, int widths, int heights) {
SDL_Rect rectangular;
rectangular.x = xs;
rectangular.y = ys;
rectangular.w = widths;
rectangular.h = heights;
}
```

It should be:

```
SDL_Rect newSDL_Rect(int xs, int ys, int widths, int heights) {
SDL_Rect rectangular;
rectangular.x = xs;
rectangular.y = ys;
rectangular.w = widths;
rectangular.h = heights;
return rectangular;
}
```

And:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 14; i++)
for ( j = 0; j < 12; j++)
```

[image]

Comment: It is not there the problem, i just typoed an older version with this stupid mistake, but the programes still has stopped without rendering anything.

Comment: What IDE are you using to run the code? I think this might be the problem.

Comment: What error are you getting ? I don't think IDE is the problem. But i'm using codeblocks v13.12 and g++ compiler on windows.

Comment: I'm not getting a error at all. When i run it, it just renders a white window. I'm also using Codeblocks, with it's MinGW compiler.

Comment: In your original [code](http://pastebin.com/M0LrLjgT) make only the above changes and recompile your code.

Comment: It actually worked, i don't understand what i was doing wrong though. Must dig into it to understand it properly. Thanks for solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your array have

```
SDL_Rect rects[14][12];
```

But you're iterating to 15 and 13th elements respectfully. This is more than array have. Fix your loops max value.

Other mistake is that your posted code don't have `return` in `newSDL_Rect` (but code in question does).

Comment: I iteretate till 15 without it, 13 respectfully. There cannot be an error there.

Comment: 14 is an error. There is only 14 elements, including 0, so last one is 13.

Comment: Ah, you are right, sorry. But that doesn't solve the problem. It still renders just a white window, but without force closing (obviously, that was because i was trying to write outside the array).

Comment: Works for me. And it isn't white, background is blue.

Answer (score 0):

> `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);`

**add ->
`SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);`**

> `SDL_Delay(5000);`

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Worked for me - you need to add after SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);